# Youtube API / JS issues with selecting videos to play

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, youtube, youtube-api

I have a videos page we created using the youtube API and Javascript in order to play our videos on an embedded player when you click the thumbnails. It works fine here: http://www.securitycameraking.com/videos.php

However, On wordpress, I tried to use similar code, but when you click on the thumbs, I'm getting a javascript error. I tried changing all of the $ to JQUERY and vice versa, but it's still not working correctly here: http://www.techprosecurity.com/videos/

I can't seem to find exactly where the conflict is. I really appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: on first look it seems like you've defined `var player` inside of `function onYouTubeIFrameAPIReady()` and therefore it's not available (in terms of scope) in `function loadVideo(videoID)` ..

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix it with your help by moving   
" var player;" outside of the function. Sometimes a second pair of eyes really helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Mentioned, "var player" was inside of "function onYouTubeIFrameAPIReady()". Once I moved it outside of the function, the thumbnails were clickable.